# gddrescue --fill-mode=+ with a map file of 0x00000000 0x608336000 + has left the partition table intact?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

I first ran this command:

```
ddrescue --force /dev/sda /dev/null HGST_RMA.map
```

I just wanted a map file for blanking (therefore `/dev/null`). And this is what my `.map` file looks like before I interrupted the run towards the end (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'d it):

[image: ddrescueview]

Then I decided to blank the disk (`/dev/zero`):

```
$ sudo ddrescue --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/sda HGST_RMA.map
GNU ddrescue 1.21
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from mapfile)
filled size:     266742 MB,  filled areas:         43
remaining size:  233363 MB,  remaining areas:     151
Current status
filled size:  500106 MB,  filled areas:    194,  current rate:  55115 kB/s
remain size:        0 B,  remain areas:      0,  average rate:  71200 kB/s
current pos:  500107 MB,  run time:     54m 37s
Finished
```

Then I ran:

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbf7dbd9f

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048  62916607  62914560    30G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       62916608  67110911   4194304     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       67110912 976773167 909662256 433.8G 83 Linux
```

This is what the initial bit of my map file looks like:

```
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.21
# Command line: ddrescue --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/sda HGST_RMA.map
# Start time:   2017-12-28 17:37:14
# Current time: 2017-12-28 18:31:57
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status
0x7470BFD000     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x608336000  +
0x608336000  0x00001000  -
0x608337000  0x380B8DD000  +
0x3E13C14000  0x00001000  -
0x3E13C15000  0x00224000  +
```

By my own estimate the partition table should have been wiped clean because of the

> ```
> 0x00000000  0x608336000  +
> ```

Why hasn't that happened and what has been blanked?

Answer (score 1):

> What has been blanked?

The clue is here:

> ```
> $ sudo ddrescue --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/sda HGST_RMA.map
> …
> Initial status (read from mapfile)
> filled size:     266742 MB,  filled areas:         43
> remaining size:  233363 MB,  remaining areas:     151
> …
> ```

For some reason `ddrescue` decided it should continue from the middle of the disk, as if the first half had already been filled. This way the partition table was left intact.

---

> Why […]?

Frankly I cannot tell. My tests with `ddrescue` 1.19 indicate this happens when the `current_status` inside the mapfile is `F` meaning "filling specified blocks". This is the case after you interrupt filling operation. Continuing seems sane, I would expect this.

But according to your `ddrescueview` screenshot, the `current_status` was `*`, "trimming non-trimmed blocks". With this status I cannot replicate the issue, my `ddrescue` fills all healthy blocks as it should. Again, this is sane and expected.

Either you hit a bug or you had altered the file(s) (and neglected to mention it here) in a way that mislead `ddrescue`. E.g. if you accidentally run this:

```
sudo ddrescue --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/null HGST_RMA.map
```

and realized your mistake ("Wait! Why is it writing so fast?"), interrupted halfway with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then your mapfile would contain `F` as `current_status`. Next you run the proper command and it "continues" from the middle of `/dev/sda`.